# I'm overwhelmed by the number of tutorials for codeIgniter. Shall I switch to it from cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, codeigniter, programming-languages

Recently I have started studying cakePHP and I love the way it's organized. But I don't seem many useful tutorials for it as codeIgniter. Am I missing anything? Shall I switch?
PS I'm a computer engineering student and have only little time to study web dev. so i need to save time.

Comment: "I'm overwhelmed by the number of tutorials for codeIgniter. Shall I switch to it from cakePHP?" - That's like saying "there's too many ways to find help, I'll go with something else".

Comment: It doesn't matter how many tutorials there are. Until you start thinking for yourself you won't make any real progress. Cake's tutorials are intended as nothing more than an introduction to the general principles and in my opinion, the Blog Tutorial does that exceptionally well. Couple it with the Bakery, the Google group and the community here and you have all you need. Doubtless the same could be said for other frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question here are the points in favor of Codeigniter

- very quick to get started with (that means not too much switching time)
- does not bind you with naming conventions and directory structures (in cakephp, you can configure it to your satisfaction, but again you should know where to configure)
- will give you a basic idea of MVC design pattern and how to make use of it to create a web application. You can build on this knowledge by using other frameworks to get to know how to make better use of it.
- as far as beginners are concerned, documentation and community support of Codeigniter is very helpful

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The decision is up to you.

The key thing is to stick with a framework so you learn enough to be productive. They're all pretty much the same but jumping between them will confuse you and delay your learning curve.

Comment: I disagree. They're not even the same much at all. I think it's important to look at several choices (and like you say, stick to one).

Comment: When I say they're the same, I mean what they are trying to achieve and the general way they go about it - assuming we're talking MVC. There aren't significant differences that would enable you to say,"For this project I'm going to use CodeIgniter and for that one I'll use Symphony." They all have perceived strengths and weaknesses, but that doesn't mean they're real strengths or weaknesses. For example CakePHP's documentation is much maligned by other framework users. In reality, it is very comprehensive with plenty of examples and the API documentation is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of codeigniter is it's documentation.

Depending on how much you used cakephp, you may need to realize that frameworks other than codeigniter often have more libraries and auto-generating funcionality (is that the right word?). Not to say that there's a shortage of commonly used libraries.

But honestly codeigniter's learning curve is so low you (If you already understand a little php) should be able to dive right in and see what you think. I honestly can't remember life before codeigniter (vanilla php).